MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE error Emacs terminals
I get Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key while I try to open an x11() window using R from within Emacs. I try both vterm, eshell, shell and ssh and all return the same error. If I try the same from terminal all works. So I suppose is an Emacs related issue. This is my ssh config file:
Host workstation
     HostName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
     User my_user
     ForwardAgent yes
     ForwardX11 yes
     ForwardX11Trusted yes

My server machine is Debian 11, my client machine is Fedora 39. Both client and server are up-to-date such as Emacs and all the package. Now I have to manually set the DISPLAY variable each time and this is very annoying.
Do you have any suggestion to automate this process? Seems that Emacs is not recognized by the remote machine.

How is Tramp related? Could you show the scenario you apply in Emacs?

I open up Emacs, load .R file ad connect to the remote workstation to run R. On the remote R if i try to do any kind of plot I get MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE message, so I have to open a terminal outside Emacs, echo $DISPLAY and set manually the display from within R, each time.

The Tramp manual contains a subsection "Running remote programs that create local X11 windows". Have you tried the given recipes?

Yes, I tried but I still get the error

I've tested the recipe. It turns out, that you need additionally to set tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options' to nil. Note, that ths variable has been renamed to tramp-use-connection-share` in Emacs 30.
